# Batch convert video to audio with VLC

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

I have a bunch of MP4 or FLV files that I need to convert into `WAV PCM 44khz 16bit stereo`

Currently I do that "the manual way" with VLC opening the transcode window, selecting the source/target files, a profile (named `Audio - CD`) made for the target format, convert, and repeat...

I know VLC works for the command line, but 1) I have no experience in Windows batch files and 2) don't know VLC options

I require that the target file has is in the subdirectory MP3 of the current directory. Possibly it must have just .wav extension and the same name of source, but I'm currently comfortable with .mp4.wav files (I'll strip the extension later).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: just to be clear... you have a bunch of Movie files, and you want to strip the audio from them, and save it to a WAV file.  Correct?

Comment: Perfect. 6chars to go... :)